# ionic - paypal - currency not supported for card type

Tags: ionic-framework, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm building an ionic mobile app and I need to include PayPal as the payment gateway in the app. So I installed the ionic PayPal plugging (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/paypal)  and implement it. Pay with Paypal is working, But pay with credit/debit card is not working. When I enter my card details it shows the following error. (Items in the app cost in HUF - Hungarian)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That error message is somewhat misleading. Yes HUF was never supported, but you're actually using a very old plugin with a credit card integration that is now not supported at all, for any currency.

So not only should you disable that credit card integration for any currency, since it will not work, but you also shouldn't use that 5-year-old plugin.

---

If you need a native SDK for PayPal payments, the only method currently supported by PayPal is the Braintree SDK: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/checkout/how-to/braintree-integration/